# How to copy a flash USB content to a folder in my hard drive

Tags: files

I want to copy all the files and folders in my flash USB to a folder in my hard drive.

My USB drive is `/dev/sdb`

Can I use the `dd` command and how ?

Answer (score 2):

- Make dir for mount : `mkdir /media/flashdrive1`
- Mount it : `mount /dev/sdb /media/flashdrive1`
- Copy it : `cp -R /media/flashdrive1 destination`

Comment: mkdir /media/flashdrive1 
mount /dev/sdb /media/flashdrive1 
cp -R /media/flashdrive1 /home/aab/miusb
after I did all the previous steps I foun the folder miusb but it is empty!!!
any suggestion

Comment: Is your USB really at /dev/sdb ? Isn't any other folders in /media folder?

Comment: This doesn't look like a partition table
Probably you selected the wrong device.

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1   ?   778135908  1919645538   570754815+  72  Unknown
/dev/sdc2   ?   168689522  2104717761   968014120   65  Novell Netware 386
/dev/sdc3   ?  1869881465  3805909656   968014096   79  Unknown
/dev/sdc4   ?  2885681152  2885736650       27749+   d  Unknown

Comment: What is the capacity of flash drive?